# jquery nav menu not marking current page when click on sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HhBEJ/3/

Despite some of the code not looking good in jsfiddle because i have background images and such - I am having a problem with my nav menu.
What I want it to do is:

When I load the page(index.htm) I want it to have a page marker ( which i have named current) to mark that I'm currently on the home page.  When I click on another page to navigate to - I want it to remove current from prev page and make curPage the new current (you can see I did this in jquery (i think i did it right)) and if i click on a sub menu.  for instance i go to  "web > web215 > JavaScript" when I click on javaScript I want the Web parent Web215 child AND the javaScript grandchild to highlight all with the 'current' id. but it's not doing it to any of them except for a quick second when i click - it's not saving it when the page loads.  I think the culprit is somewhere in here:

```
function youAreHere() {
var pathName = $(location).attr('pathname');
var curPage = pathName.substring(pathName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == curPage) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'current');
    } else if (curPage == '') {
        $('a:first').attr('id', 'current');
    }
}); //END function
```

I know when i put an alert it's calling the page correctly and it's working as intended but the current class isn't either A: staying after it loads or B: loading up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css is wrong, you are setting the id of current to the a tag but in the css you are setting the id of current to the li tag. This is what you need:

```
div#menu li a#current {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 16px;
 z-index: 6;
 background: transparent url('../images/menu_level1_item.png') repeat-x scroll 0pt 100%;
}
div#menu li a#current ul {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: WOW! hahah I was grueling over this for hours and it was just two pesky 'a's holding me up :(

Thank you very much!

Comment: don't worry you are not the only one, it happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: One more quick question - that fixed it not staying but the second part is how to I make it so that if i'm clicking an anchor in the third level of an item, that it selects the first level and it's second level as well? because right now - once i click on WEB it will highlight but if i click a sub menu of WEB  then the WEB de-selects  and only the  sub menu selects

Comment: well I would recommend actually storing the pages in a folder hierarchy then you could check for each level which URL links to the root of that folder and set that to current

Comment: im going to have to look up how to do that, since I have no clue how to - Thank you again though!